# Can't get javascript length-related regex to work

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a Javascript regex that matches words with less than 3 letters (and doesn't match longer words). I can't see why this doesn't work.

```
<html>
        <body>
                <script>
                var re = new RegExp("(\W|^)\w{0,2}(\W|$)", "gi");
                var text = "ab ab";
                var matched = re.test(text);
                document.write(matched)

                </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

I tried to get a minimum example, but I have more requirements, if the example is not complete I'll edit and add whatever is necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `\`s are being treated as Javascript escapes, so the actual value of the regex is `"(W|^)w{0,2}(W|$)"`.

Instead, use a regex literal: `/(\W|^)\w{0,2}(\W|$)/gi`

Comment: nice +1. I know it was in the OP, but I don't think you need the `i` modifier with `\w`  http://jsfiddle.net/cordsen/VQRPK/